# Conditional tag to get AMP image url

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, google-search-console, accelerated-mobile-page

In Blogger, I am making my website amp supported and for this, in my post, I change all `<img to <amp-img`.
But in structured data I Use following Code:

```html
<div class='none' itemprop='image' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='https://schema.org/ImageObject'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
        <amp-img expr:src='data:post.firstImageUrl' itemprop='image'/>
        <meta expr:content='data:post.firstImageUrl' itemprop='url'/>
      </b:if>
      <meta content='800' itemprop='width'/> <!--Images should be at least 696 pixels wide.-->
      <meta content='800' itemprop='height'/>
    </div>
```

Whenever I Check This Tool in Structured data testing Tool.Above code can't extract `<amp-img` URL because it was used to extract `<img` URL only.
How can I  Fix This?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Searching a Lot On Many  Forums I Found This Solution to My Question.In Post Use `<amp-img` with NoScript from [amp guideline](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/amp_replacements#images).

```html
<amp-img src="images/sunset.jpg"
  width="264"
  height="195">
  <noscript>
    <img src="images/sunset.jpg" width="264" height="195" />
  </noscript>
</amp-img>
```

This can Two  Version of your Image one is the amp and another is non-amp simultaneously.